# Excel : Highlight Max Value for Multiple Values appearing Multiple Times in Adjacent column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do a conditional formatting so I can highlight the maximum number row for each of the adjacent Business Unit.

For example, Row 4 and Row 12 for C22 and Row 11 for C50 ( Refer to image ). These are the only two columns. I have multiple BUs, but limited it to 2 for simplicity's sake.

Is there anyway this can be done? I have tried MAXIFS, MATCH, but to no avail.

[image]

I just need Rows 4,11,12 highlighted as the are the maximum value in Column A or their respective Business Unit in Column B.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Maximum number row? What is that? I guess you have typos. Please edit and explain properly. Also, include original data and try to make a minimal example.

Comment: You want the max of A, which would highlight both rows 4 and 12 for C22?  Or the last value in the column for that BU which would only highlight row 12 for C22?

Comment: Yes Scott, so rows 4 and 12 for C22 and Row 11 for C21. A simple Max would work if it was just one business unit, but I have multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MAXIFS()

```
=AND($A1 = MAXIFS($A:$A,$B:$B,$B1),$A1<>0)
```

[image]

If you do not have MAXIFS then use AGGREGATE, but one must limit the data range:

```
=AND($A1 = AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$12/($B$1:$B$12=$B1),1),$A1<>0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is all I required! Appreciate the help!

Comment: I realized my excel does not have MAXIF which is why it wasn't working. I will use MAX(IF(...) instead. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used AGGREGATE as you had mentioned and it worked perfectly. In addition, the other method which worked for me is also something I posted in case someone else has a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer it using the following ( given my Excel does not support MAXIF)

=$A2=IF($A2>0,MAX(IF($B2=$B:$B,$A:$A)))